# How to map incoming messages to a consumer group in Azure Eventhub

Tags: c#, azure-eventhub

I am trying to use Azure EventHub in order to process messages and it works fine as long as I have one sender and one consumer.

I simple make my consumer listen to a specific Consumer Grooup and all is fine

Now the problem is when I send different types of messages that I want processed by different Consumer Group I dont see how that can be done

I am creating my sender like this

```
private static EventHubProducerClient eventHubClient = new EventHubProducerClient(eventHubConnectionString, eventHubName);
```

But I find no way to tell it what Consumer Group it should send to, it simple sends to hub itself and that hub has multiple resource groups

How do I decide what consumergroup gets this message?

I googled for hours without finding the way to "map" input messages from specific senders  to a specific output Consumer Group

Comment: resource group? do you mean Consumer group?

Comment: Yes sorry I edited the question

Comment: Actually, you cannot do that if you know what's consumer group. Messages are sent to partitions, partitions are included in each consumer group.

Comment: OK but the same problem persists, how do I know what partition a message is send to and how do I know what partition a consumer group is in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot specify which message is sent to a specified Consumer group. Messages are sent to partitions, partitions are all included in each consumer group, you can check the diagram in this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-features#consumer-groups). The screenshot as below:

[image]

> Now for you question: when I send different types of messages that I
>   want processed by different Consumer Group I dont see how that can be
>   done.

As a workaround, when you send messages, you can [specify a property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.eventdata?view=azure-dotnet#properties) for each message. When read these messages from consumer group, you can also use the property to determine if you want to process it or abandon it.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I dont want a workaround I am happy to send to different partitions, but how? I cannot find any decent documentation that shows how to do this, how do I specify the partition to send to? And how do I specify what partition a consumer group is in?

Comment: 1. how do I specify the partition to send to? For this, you can specify a partition_key when send data, but it just makes sure all the data with the same partition_key in a same partition, but cannot specify which partition is used. 2. And how do I specify what partition a consumer group is in? You should know one thing, each Consumer group contains all the partitions.

Comment: This is so confusing so it means every event hub name space can only handle one type of messages as they need to be processed by the same type receiver?

Comment: @MattDouhan, no. Event hub namespace is not equal to Event hub instance. Event hub namespace can contains more Event hub instances, and the consumer group is connected to a Event hub instance. Hope it clears.

Comment: Ahh ok so within the same namespace I add one HUB for each type of message, so the different consumer groups is more to handle different types of processing of the same messages and not to handle different types of messages, that kind of makes sense

Comment: To address the question of "how do I specify the partition to send to",  you would assign the partition identifier as part of the options when creating the batch. The following sample illustrates how to do so:  https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/master/sdk/eventhub/Azure.Messaging.EventHubs/samples/Sample07_PublishAnEventBatchToASpecificPartition.cs

Comment: To address "And how do I specify what partition a consumer group is in", you don't.   Every partition of an Event Hub can be ready by any consumer groups of that Event Hub.  Think of consumer groups as a way to organize your event readers into one logical unit and help them coordinate.